# Issue with using Python to upload Adobe AEM - converting curl command to requests

Tags: python, aem

Trying to convert the this curl command to python.

`curl -u admin:xxxxxxxx -F file=@"package.zip" -F name="package.zip" -F force=true -F install=true http://host:port/crx/packmgr/service.jsp`

Attempted using this, get a 200 success code but printing the response text and reviewing the server shows the upload didn't work. Could someone please advise what I am doing wrong here?

```
    import requests

    files = {
        'file': ('package.zip', open('package.zip', 'rb')),
        'name': (None, 'package.zip'),
        'force': (None, 'true'),
        'install': (None, 'true'),
    }

    response = requests.post('http://host:port/crx/packmgr/service.jsp', files=files, auth=('admin', 'xxxxxxxx'))


    print(response.headers)
    print(response.text)
```

Comment: That might be it. Will test it out as soon as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to import Basic authentication

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

response = requests.post('http://host:port/crx/packmgr/service.jsp', 
files=files, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', '****'))
```

Update:

```
 import requests
 from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
 url = 'http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp'
 files = { 'file': ('mypackage.zip', 
 open('/Users/zospakir/Projects/mypackage.zip', 'rb'), 
 'application/zip')}
 data = dict(name='mypackage.zip', force='true',install='true')
 response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, auth=('admin', 
 '***'))
```

Comment: Altered the code as suggested but no real difference.

Comment: The script connects and then dumps all the argument options

Comment: @user796632, I have updated my answer, you were also missing content type.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The problem was in how the source file was being parsed.

```
   datafile=fullfile + "/" + filename
   url = "http://{}:{}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp".format(server,port)
   form_data = dict(
        file=(filename, open(datafile, 'rb'), 'application/zip', dict()),
        name=package.rstrip('.zip'),
        strict=True,
        force=(None, 'true'),
        install=(None, 'true')
   )
   resp = requests.post(url, auth=('admin', passwd), files=form_data)   
   if resp.status_code == 200:
       print(resp.headers)
       print(resp.text)
       print('Success!...  Response code 200')
       status = "Upload of " + package + " to " + url + "successful"
       package_location=pkg_group(resp.text)
       package_path=package_location + "/" + package
       #mailer.send(status,resp.text)
   else:
       print(resp.headers)
       print(resp.text)
       status='Upload of ' + package +  'Error detected!'
       sys.exit(1)
```